# Is there a workaround for the server browser showing no servers?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

There's a bug that's [existed since the game was released](http://steamcommunity.com/app/219640/discussions/0/846944052766211639/) that causes the game to show no servers in the server browser.

Are there any known workarounds for this bug?

Comment: Is the bug still present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by three separate bugs:  the "perspective" filter changes randomly, it doesn't show up correctly in the UI, and it doesn't correctly filter servers.

### HOW TO FIX:

- Start Chivalry, go to the server browser
- Hit *Advanced Filters* in the lower-right
- Set *Perspective* to *First-Person*, then save
- Open *Advanced Filters* again
- Set *Perspective* to *All*, then save

### IF THAT DOESN'T WORK...

- In Windows, open the folder

  ```
  %UserProfile%\Documents\my games\Chivalry Medieval Warfare\UDKGame\Config
  ```

  *Note: If you are running Windows XP, the directory is*

  ```
  %UserProfile%\My Documents\my games\Chivalry Medieval Warfare\UDKGame\Config
  ```
- Close Chivalry
- Open *UDKUI.ini* in a text editor
- Search for the string

  ```
  [AOC.AOCView_Frontend_JoinGame]
  ```

  You should find two lines that look something like this:

  ```
  [AOC.AOCView_Frontend_JoinGame]
  SavedFilter=(ServerName=,MapName=,GameSpeed=0,GameMode=0,MaxPing=0,Perspective=2,HidePassworded=False,HideEmptyServers=True,HideFullServers=True,RequireVAC=False,UseRankLimits=False,MinRank=0,MaxRank=0)
  ```
- Delete both those lines, then save the file and restart Chivalry

### IF ALL ELSE FAILS...

Delete the entire Config folder mentioned above.  This will cause you to lose your configuration and player-customization settings :(